# Deploy MVC 5 Bootstrap 3 Glyphicon Not Display

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I've got display problem after deploy MVC 5.1 with bootstrap 3.0.0 to production. Glyphicon doesn't appear and bootstrap css seems not load properly.

On server (it is fine in production):
[image]

On client (this is the problem):
[image]

Comment: Make sure your fonts are loaded. IIS by default may not serve the files with `woff` extension so you have to configure it a little.

Comment: @Zabavsky How to make sure that fonts are loaded?

Comment: Open the browser developer tool (usually it's `F12` key) and see whether you have any `404` errors in the consose.

Comment: @Zabavsky There is no error 404 in console

Comment: @Zabavsky I set IIS MIME Type setup for .woff files and glyph still not displaying

Comment: Could you please have a look at my answer on [Bootstrap glyphicon not showing in Form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35659094/bootstrap-glyphicon-not-showing-in-form/35660280#35660280)?

Answer (score 0):

Download bootstrap package from here : 
http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download
and paste all the files from **fonts** folder of Bootstrap package into the **fonts** folder of your asp.net application. And make sure that you are uploading those font files to the server. To do so, Press Ctrl+Shift+I --> "Network" Tab in Chrome and see if all the resources are loading. That should solve the problem.

Comment: I already download the full package and paste all fonts to application then publish to server, but nothing change

Comment: It runs well in Chrome or Firefox, but not in IE 9, I've seen Network in IE that only glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot is loaded