# Bootstrap glyphicon not showing in Form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying out different ways to do a form with a confirm. I have the following in form as well as just a hyperlink. The hyperlink below is displaying the glyphicon correctly but the submit button inside the form is just displaying as "submit" in a gray button. Does the CSS need to be different in the submit button vs a hyperlink?

```
<div class="text-center">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Patrol", new { id = item.MemberId }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <input type="submit" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to remove this record?')" />
    }

    <a href="@Url.Action("Delete", new {id = item.MemberId})" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to remove this record?')"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `Firebug` or another debugger, find the `css` file in which the `glyphicon` is defined. In this `css` file check the `src` location at `@font-face` section. You might need to make some changes (i.e. adding or removing ' **../** ') in the `src` section according to your `glyphicons` location in your project as shown below:

```
src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
```

*or*

```
src: url('../../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
```

On the other hand, if some of the application files are not displayed after publishing it to the server, you might need to apply the following changes regarding to file path:

*from*

```
~/../../Content/images/img.png
```

*to*

```
./../../Content/images/img.png
```

And under `Properties` window of the related files, check if the properties set for them as shown below:

Build Action : *Content*
Copy to Output Directory: *Do not copy*