# Bootstrap Glyphicons not displaying in angular2

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, web, angular, glyphicons

I am trying to use bootstrap glyphicons in my angular2 app. I have installed bootstrap using the command npm install bootstrap --save
My code snippet is

```html
 <button *ngIf="pos.name == uname" type="button" class="btn btn-default       btn-sm delete" (click)="DeleteBulletin();">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash glyph"></span>  Delete
 </button>
```

I have included bootstrap in my styleUrls-
    styleUrls: ['node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css', 'app/home.component.css']

The glyphicon appears as shown-
[image]

Comment: look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35659094/bootstrap-glyphicon-not-showing-in-form/35660280#35660280

Comment: You could check the console for a `404` error, where it tries to load the font file.

Comment: fyi, Bootstrap 4 dropped the Glyphicon icon font

Comment: Dropped the Glyphicons icon font. If you need icons, some options are:
the upstream version of Glyphicons
Octicons
Font Awesome

Answer (score 30):

Boostrap 4 **[does not support](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#components)** Glyphicons anymore, you can use [Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/) instead:

```
npm install --save fortawesome/fontawesome-free
```

and add the css File to your .angular-cli.json

```
"apps": [
          {
             ....
             "styles": [
                "styles.css",
                "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
                "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"
             ],
             ...
         }
       ]

],
```

Replace CSS class with the Font Awesome classes:

```
<i class="navbar-toggler-icon fa fa-bars"> </i>
```

recompile app: `ng serve`

**Update:**
Since Font Font-Awesome 5 and Angular 5 there is an offical angular-fontawesome package available:

https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome#installation

Comment: In my case I didn't have a angular-cli.json file. Instead I added to src/styles.css:

@import "~font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"

After this it worked as a charm!

Comment: With the above comment I noticed that only the regular icons would work for me. Not the other ones. By following the steps in the following article, everything works and I can use types icons instead of using clases: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-font-awesome

Comment: See [Official Angular component for Font Awesome 5](https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome) for simple installation

Answer (score 17):

You have to import

`<link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.3.6" data-semver="3.3.6" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />`

to your index.html

Answer (score 5):

I installed bootstrap3 as npm install bootstrap@3 and it started working

just need to add in angular-cli.json:-

```
   "styles": [
        "styles.css",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
     ],
```

Comment: I have the same problem. I tried this solution, but no luck... any ideas?

Comment: The problem was having the bootstrap 4.x in my index.html --> replacing it with <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> worked.

Comment: Thanks. My problem was referencing bootstrap.min.css instead of bootstrap.css.

Comment: this works！ bootstrap.min.css instead of bootstrap.css

Answer (score 3):

There is **angular-cli-build.js** file of root of the project if your application has been scaffold by **angular-cli** (using 'ng init' or 'ng new').

**angular-cli-build.js** instructs build of the project (using 'ng serve' or 'ng build') to place 3rd-party libraries into **vendor** folder.

There is **fonts** folder, in bootstrap distribution folder, holding glyphicons files. Those bootstrap files needs to be placed into vendor folder too.

**angular-cli-build.js**:

```
// Angular-CLI build configuration
// This file lists all the node_modules files that will be used in a build
// Also see https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/3rd-party-libs

/* global require, module */

var Angular2App = require('angular-cli/lib/broccoli/angular2-app');

module.exports = function(defaults) {
  return new Angular2App(defaults, {
    vendorNpmFiles: [
      'systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js',
      'systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
      'zone.js/dist/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
      'es6-shim/es6-shim.js',
      'reflect-metadata/**/*.+(ts|js|js.map)',
      'rxjs/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
      '@angular/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
      'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css',
      'bootstrap/dist/fonts/*'
    ]
  });
};
```

For completeness, setup process for bootstrap was in those few steps below:

Commnad line:

```
npm install bootstrap --save
```

**index.html**:

```
<link href="/vendor/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Restart 'ng serve' or just rebuild with 'ng build'

Here is result of page source:

[image: Glyphicon with trach glyph]

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Bootstrap 4, it doesn't include glyphicon in self release.
So you coud use another icon package such as FontAwesome or installed the Glyphicons separately.

I am using FontAwesome and that dependencies in my cases:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "1.0.0-beta.9",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.12.9",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.6.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2"
  }
```

In HTML templates just place a code like that:

```
<i class="fa fa-refresh" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Answer (score 2):

if you are using bootstrap 4 glyphicon is no longer supported you should try an old version

Answer (score 1):

if you include bootstrap files through styleUrls this will make an issue, I don't know why, but I found that the borwser looks at different location for glyphicons.

```
@Component({
   moduleId: module.id,
   selector: 'app-projects',
   templateUrl: 'projects.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['projects.component.css','../../vendor/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'],
   providers:[ProjectsService]
})
```

using above method for calling bootstrap stylesheet file causes following error
"GET http://localhost:4200/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff "

what you can see from the error is that the browser is looking at `localhost:4200/fonts/...` where it should be `localhost:4200/vendor/bootstrap/dist/fonts/...`

anyway, a workaround is to make sure that you added the `dist` folder of bootstrap inside `angular-cli-build.js` file in `vendorNpmFiles` array as `'bootstrap/dist/**/*.+(js|css|eot|ttf|woff|woff2)'` and remove bootstrap stylesheet from `styleUrls`.

then add to the index.html the following line:

```
<link href="/vendor/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

dont forget to `ng serve` or `ng build`

Answer (score 0):

Please run

```
npm install glyphicons --save
```

and than please import glyphicons in your component

```
 import icons from 'glyphicons';
    var icons = require('glyphicons');
    console.info('This is' + icons.heart+ ' Glyphicons!')
```

You can check once in your browser console.

Answer (score 0):

The advice with FontAwesome is correct but only partially. If you just follow the FontAwesome instructions you will fail in an Angular project.

Instead check the hint on [this page](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/angular):

> Font Awesome now has an official Angular component that’s available
>   for all who want to easily use our icons in projects. If you are using
>   Angular, you need the angular-fontawesome package or Web Fonts with
>   CSS.

Okay this means **in an Angular project you need to use the following package**: [Angular FontAwesome](https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome)

The best page that I have found for me as I am using NPM was [this page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-font-awesome).

So basically you need to:

1. Install FontAwesome in NPM
2. Import the module AngularFontAwesomeModule in your **app.module.ts**
3. Add the CSS in the **angular-cli.json** file

The details are all described in the link above.

4. To finally add an icon you can add a power-off icon in the **app.component.html** file:

Code:

```
<fa-icon [icon]="faPowerOff"></fa-icon>
```

5. AND you need to add the code in the related **app.component.ts** file:

Code:

```
    import { faPowerOff } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
    ...
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
      faPowerOff = faPowerOff;
    ...
```

**ONE IMPORTANT NOTE!**

Please realize you need to install the correct **version of AngularFontawesome in NPM for your Angular version**. Check [this page](https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome#installation) for the compatibility table.

I used Angular 5 so I had to install it like this:

```
npm install @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome@0.1.1
```

The entry will then be added to your **package.json** file.

Answer (score 0):

I did the same as @Sebastian Viereck . But i did

```
npm install --save-dev @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
```

and on the angular.json

```
"styles": ["node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
           "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css",
            "src/styles.css"
 ],
```

It looks that fontawesome has a new paid version

Answer (score 0):

From https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_icons.asp -

> Bootstrap 4 does not have its own icon library (Glyphicons from bootstrap 3 are not supported in BS4). However, there are many free icon libraries to choose from, such as Font Awesome and Google Material Design Icons. To use Font Awesome icons, follow these steps:

Install Font-Awesome from the terminal in your project folder

```
npm install --save font-awesome
```

and add the following line to your main stylesheet -

```
@import "~font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css";
```

You can now access all the icons available in the installed Font-Awesome library. Refer this link for the complete list of icons - [Official Font Awesome Website](https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery)