# How can i place all the glyphicons to one folder while building in angular4?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

i have a application created using cli command. my angular-cli.json file looks like this

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "lienholder"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",       
        "style.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "component": {}
  }
}
```

now when i build the applicaiton using the command

> ng build --target=development --environment=dev

it creates a dist folder i which have all the following files like this

```
dist
    -assests
        images
            image1
            image2
        style.css
    -favicon.ico
    -glyphicons-halflings-regular.448c34a56d699c29117a.woff2
    -glyphicons-halflings-regular.448c34a56d699c29117a.svg
    -glyphicons-halflings-regular.448c34a56d699c29117a.ttf
    -glyphicons-halflings-regular.448c34a56d699c29117a.eot
    -glyphicons-halflings-regular.448c34a56d699c29117a.woff
    -index.html
    -inline.bundle.js
    -inline.bundle.js.map
    -main.bundle.js
    -main.bundle.js.map
    -polyfills.bundle.js
    -polyfills.bundle.js.map
    -styles.bundle.js
    -styles.bundle.js.map
    -vendor.bundle.js   
    -vendor.bundle.js.map
```

now, wht i want is, instead of having all the glyphicons on the root, i want to place all the glyphicons file inside a folder, something like this

```
glyphicons-folder
    -glyphicons-halflings-regular.448c34a56d699c29117a.woff2
    -glyphicons-halflings-regular.448c34a56d699c29117a.svg
    -glyphicons-halflings-regular.448c34a56d699c29117a.ttf
    -glyphicons-halflings-regular.448c34a56d699c29117a.eot
    -glyphicons-halflings-regular.448c34a56d699c29117a.woff
```

how can i do that?

**UPDATE**

this is how the folder is placed inside the node_modules folder

[image]

[image]

Comment: but will that not break your application as the path you might have defined for them will be different ?

Answer (score 2):

Modify your `angular-cli.json` like

```
"assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico",
        "glyphicons-folder"
      ],
```

And copy all your icon fonts in to that folder.

Or

Create a folder `glyphicons-folder` inside `assets` folder so you do not have to modify your `angular-cli.json` this way. Whatever is inside `assets` is gets outputed by default.

But I would do something like `assets/fonts/glyphicons`

> What `assets` config option does it is outputs the folder content or a
>   file so you can reference that as it is in you app. By default
>   `assets` and `favicon.ico` you get configured this way.

**UPDATE:**
I think you need to see this https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6147#issuecomment-298858109:

> glyphicons is referenced in bootstrap.css. This is just
>   webpack/AngularCLI doing it's thing including all files needed for
>   your CSS.
>
> It doesn't really hurt that it's there other than OCD, does it? :p If
>   you really want to remove it you could build from less/sass instead.
>   Copy bootstrap.less/sass into your project and change all the imports
>   to point to the correct files then remove @import
>   "bootstrap/glyphicons";.

Sounds like you have to live with that for now or build it from less/sass yourself as per comment above.

Comment: i have a bootstrap file in the location ../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css, which i have added it in the angular-cli.json file like this, "styles": [
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",             
      ],
this is why i am getting the glyphicons file, if i move the glyphicons file inside the assest folder, will that break my css?

Comment: try to run `ng serve` to test and check this if wont work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37916272/bootstrap-glyphicons-not-displaying-in-angular2

Comment: please see my update, i have described how the file is arranges inside the node_modules, so it wont break if i run the app using ng serve command, it would be a concern when we try to build it, i want to change the location so that it would refrence to the folder assests/fonts/glyphicons instead of just glyphicons. which it is happening right now, any idea how can i do that

Comment: @LijinDurairaj just updated the answer and sound like there is no easy way to get rid of `glyphicons` from the `dist` folder, however it is just a`dist` folder anyway so it should not hurt.