# Angular CLI outputs the font-awesome font files the dist root

Tags: angular, angular-cli, font-awesome, webpack-2

Do you have to `eject` your angular-cli and override the webpack configuration in order to place the `font-awesome` fonts into the assets/fonts folder? I have this angular-cli and I include the font-awesome this way in my `angular-cli.json`:

```
"styles": [
        "styles.css",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"
      ],
```

but when I do `ng build --prod` I get everything built correctly however all font-awesome fonts are located in the root (where the styles.css is).

Can you configure this through angular-cli.json or do you have to do it via scripting in the packages.json?

Looking at the wiki for assets management (https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-asset-configuration), I tried this:

```
  "assets": [
    { "glob": "**/*", "input": "./assets/", "output": "./assets/" },
    { "glob": "favicon.ico", "input": "./", "output": "./" },
    { "glob": "**/*", "input": "../node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/*", "output": "./assets/fonts/" }
  ]
```

But that didn't work.

UPDATE:

Looks like is not possible? --> https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6637

Comment: it might be configured in webpack

Answer (score 0):

I think you just followed http://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/include-font-awesome.md during `ng serve/build` once cli seeing you referencing the `font-awesome` it is just copying the fonts files like it is in to the root.

Seems like it is similar issue [How can i place all the glyphicons to one folder while building in angular4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46095318/how-can-i-place-all-the-glyphicons-to-one-folder-while-building-in-angular4) angular cli just handling the fonts referenced by `font-awesome.css` this way so it is just affecting the `output/dist` folder that client browser does not care about so it is should not hurt.