# Bootstrap 4 Glyphicons not showing on Angular 4 project

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, glyphicons

I'm working on an Angular 4 Project using Bootstrap 4 with Sass, and I want to use the glyphicons but when I use the following code:

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span>Like</button>
```

For example, when making a "like" button, the icon doesn't show.

I configured the project to compile the SCSS stylesheets with the `ng-serve` command, my `angular-cli.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "front-end-informatorio"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/main.scss"

      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "scss",
    "component": {}
  }
}
```

I tried linking this in my `index.html`:

```
<link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.3.6" data-semver="3.3.6" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css"/>
```

It made the icons work, but also also changed the whole style of my project.

How do I achieve it without overlapping the styles?

Comment: Please see this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49920875/5546886 Nice soluation.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Bootstrap 4 dropped Glyphicons support. (see: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#components)

This means that you'll need to use some other icon font, like [Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.com/).

### Quick start for Font Awesome

1. Grab the script from the [get started page](https://fontawesome.com/get-started)
2. Paste it in your `<head>`
3. **Start using!** Search for the icons on [FontAwesome.com](https://fontawesome.com/icons)
4. Explore the [docs](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/svg-with-js) to unleash the full potential of Font Awesome!

Example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Bootstrap + Font Awesome</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <!-- display 4 class makes the font size increase -->
      <h1 class="display-4"><i class="fab fa-stack-overflow"></i></h1>
      <p>That was easy! <i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i></p>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Works also with buttons! <i class="fas fa-link"></i></button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

### Angular Font Awesome component

The Font Awesome team is working on an Angular Font Awesome component. It is right now in pre-release, but you can find it [here](https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome).